# Calcular valores de cada coluna de uma tabela html

Tags: php, javascript, html, table, matemática

Estou querendo calcular valores de uma tabela. Cada coluna tem valores diferentes, ao final da tabela, gostaria de informar o valor total. Segue abaixo o meu html.

```html
<table class="table table-striped m-table m-table--head-bg-success">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nº doc</th>
      <th>Valor doc</th>
      <th>Correção doc</th>
      <th>Multa doc</th>
      <th>Valor extra doc</th>
      <th>Valor Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php 
      $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM doc where cod_doc = '$id_get' ORDER BY data ASC ");          
      $sql->execute();   $a = 0  ;        
           while($row=$sql->fetch(PDO:: FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
              $a++;
        $pct_multa = 2;
        $pct_ext = 1;
        $pct_cob = 10; 
        $valor_doc = $row['valor_doc'];
        $data = $row['data'];     
    ?>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">
        <? echo $row['numero_doc']?>
      </th>

      <td id="sum1"> 
        <? echo str_replace('.', ',', $valor_doc)?>
      </td>
      <td id="sum2">
        <? echo str_replace('.', ',', $doc_correcao)?>
      </td>
      <td id="sum3">
        <? echo valorMulta($valor_doc,$pct_multa) ?>
      </td>
      <td id="sum4">
        <? echo valorext($valor_doc,$pct_ext) ?>
      </td>
    
      <td id="sum5"><span class="m-widget6__text m--align-right m--font-boldest m--font-brand">
              <? echo valorTotal($valor_doc,$pct_ext,$pct_multa, $data) ?>
             </span></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Criei uma id para cada td (Ex: id="sum1") total da coluna que quero calcular. Como posso proceder ? Desde já, agradeço a preciosa atenção de vocês.

Comment: vc quer calcular usando php ou js?

Comment: Js .. Vou criar uma tabela ao final com o somatório de cada coluna. Apenas para visualização .

Comment: A tabela já traz as informações corretas. Só não faz o calculo ao final . Pois não sei como fazer.

Comment: vc esta usando Jquery? Ou js puro?

Comment: Utilizo jQuery .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente, o atributo `id` é algo que deve ser unico, então ao invés de `id` use `class`:

```
<tr>
    <th scope="row">
    <? echo $row['numero_doc']?>
    </th>
    <td class="sum1">
        <? echo str_replace('.', ',', $valor_doc)?>
    </td>
    <td class="sum2">
        <? echo str_replace('.', ',', $doc_correcao)?>
    </td>
    <td class="sum3">
        <? echo valorMulta($valor_doc,$pct_multa) ?>
    </td>
    <td class="sum4">
        <? echo valorext($valor_doc,$pct_ext) ?>
    </td>    
    <td class="sum5">
        <span class="m-widget6__text m--align-right m--font-boldest m--font-brand">
            <? echo valorTotal($valor_doc,$pct_ext,$pct_multa, $data) ?>
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

No `Jquery` você pode repetir o exemplo para cada coluna:

```
var sum1 = 0;

$.each($('.sum1'),function(){
    var num = parseInt($(this).text().replace(/[^0-9]/g,''));
    sum1 += num;
});
```

- `.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')` mantem apenas os números do texto estraido pelo `text()`;
- `parseInt()` transforma a `string` em `integer`;

Depois basta reformar o valor para monetário e incluir onde será exibido.

Comment: Perfeito. Vou realizar um teste agora. Obrigado!

Comment: Wees Smith, não deu muito certo. a td sum1 aparece 10 vezes. será que esse é o problema ?

Comment: Desconsidera a minha mensagem acima. Fiz um console.log na variável. está calculando corretamente.

Comment: sim, ele vai somar todas as tds q tiverem a class sum1, etc